# When you make a private repo public, will the commits you made while it was private become public?

Tags: github, repository

Currently I'm working in a private repo in Github, so the commits I make don't show up on my public profile.

Later, when the project is finished I will make the repo public.

Will the commits I made back when it was private then show up on my public profile with the correct dates?

Comment: Who will be notified when you make a private repo public?

Comment: well, if you were doing a code test and used the same account for your current work. That will be odd.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried it myself, and yes, it does indeed make the past commits public.